# opening multiple files using a loop in c

Tags: arrays, c, loops, text-files, fopen

i have three files, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, and i'd like to open them in a loop so i can perform operations on each file through the loop. do i use arrays? how can i do that? currently my code only opens one file, and it looks like this:

```
char filename[] = "file1.txt", record[100];
FILE *fPtr;
fPtr = fopen(filename, "r");

     while (fgets(record, 100, fPtr))
     {
      //code where i look for certain strings in the file
     }
fclose (fPtr);
```

would it be possible to make `fPtr` open those 3 files, one after another closes, so that all 3 files can be looped through to perform some operations? would appreciate it if someone could explain how.

Comment: Loop over `1`, `2` and `3` and use [`snprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to create the filename?

Comment: Hi, What kind of operation do you intend to perform on all files? Is it the same or does it vary depending upon file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to co it by iterating them in a loop. Let's say you have these three files:

```
src : $ cat file1.txt 
StackOverflow is cool
src : $ cat file2.txt 
I use StackOverflow daily
src : $ cat file3.txt 
I use Github daily
src : $ cat file4.txt
I use StackO
verflow on weekends
```

You can put file names in an array like this:

```c
char fileNames[3][10] = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"};
```

I noticed from comment that you want to search for some strings in these files. As an example, If I want to do a search of string "StackOverflow" in these files, I can simply iterate over them and call a search method which would search for provided string when provided a pointer to file and string to search. Here is how it would look:

```c
char searchStr[] = "StackOverflow";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  FILE *pFile = fopen(fileNames[i], "r");
  bool bExists = searchInFile(pFile, searchStr);
  if (bExists) {
    printf("%s contains %s\n", fileNames[i], searchStr);
  }
  fclose(pFile);
}
```

You can extract common logic for searching the file in `searchInFile` method:

```c
bool searchInFile(FILE *pFile, char *str) {
  char buffer[1024]; // buffer to read whole file in memory
  char temp[100]; // temporary buffer to read line

  buffer[0] = '\0'; // Initialize empty string
  while (fgets(temp, 100, pFile) != NULL) {
      temp[strlen(temp) - 1] = '\0';
      strcat(buffer, temp); // Concatenate lines into single string
  }

  return strstr(buffer, str) != NULL; // Search for target string
}
```

My output when I ran above code:

```
file1.txt contains StackOverflow
file2.txt contains StackOverflow
file4.txt contains StackOverflow
```

Comment: Beware [*false negatives*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) when the search string occurs at the boundary: ie, 1st `fgets()` reads `"... ... ...StackO"`, 2nd one reads `"verflow... ... ..."`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I've updated my answer to handle the case you mentioned. Please review whenever you revisit this and provide feedback if possible.

Comment: There's still a couple "what ifs"... just letting you, and OP, know and maybe opt to leave the code as-is (it's good enough for most purposes) ... 1) file is larger than buffer 2) file does not end with a newline, ie `"...flow"<EOF>`, not the usual `"...flow\n"<EOF>`

Comment: ohk, Thanks a lot for taking time to review!

Comment: I believe files ending without a final `'\n'` is much more common on Windows than on Un*x